# Explanation and/or examples of client code and public interface in Python?

Tags: python, interface, client, public

I understand client code as a code that a 'client' has access to and can run whatever modules it imports, but I do not understand what a public interface is.

We learned in class that it's some sort of docstring in generic parent class that provides enough information to run inherited child classes without having access to said child classes. I think...

Comment: Your question is too vague and unspecific. Find some example, try to understand it, and if you are stuck, ask a specific question about it.

Comment: It depends on context I'm afraid.  IT people are very bad at mixing jargon, and using the same term to mean different things.  'client' is an example of that, and so is 'child', but just remember that those imply a relationship, whereas 'public' implies "everybody" including those unrelated.  You should really ask your tutor to clarify.